# Different method behavior in child class from abstract parent class

Tags: java

I'm working on a drawing project, and I have certain tools (i.e. a drawing brush, an eraser, etc.) that are their own classes, each inheriting from an abstract Tool class with some basic properties and abstract/non-abstract methods. The main problem I am seeing is when I need to change the color for these tools, I want to figure out a way to do it for all tools, but also allow certain tools (like an Eraser) to remain unchanged since it's color should always just be the background color.

I am receiving the `onColorChange(int newColor)` method call from elsewhere, but this is the starting point for where I trigger the color change for the tools. Right now, it only changes the color for the active tool, but that means each tool has a different color set and it gets confusing.

I want a color change to trigger the `setColor()` method for all of the Tools, so I thought about putting the setColor() method as a static method in the Tool class, but that wouldn't allow me to override in the Eraser class to prevent the color being changed.

Anyone have any ideas on how to implement this? TLDR: I want the onColorChange() event to trigger a color change for all of the tools, but also I want to override that in the Eraser class so no color change takes place for that tool.

Currently, with my implementation, I have the following:

```
Tool currentTool;
Tool myBrush;
Tool myEraser;
Tool myPencil;

// This is called from elsewhere
pubic void setup() {
   myBrush = new Brush();
   myEraser = new Eraser();
   myPencil = new Pencil();
   currentTool = myBrush;
}

// This is called from elsewhere
public void onColorChange(int newColor) {
   currentTool.setColor(newColor);
}
```

**Tool.java**

```
public abstract class Tool {

    protected String toolName;

    protected Paint myPaint;

    public String getToolName() {
        return mToolName;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return myPaint.getColor();
    }

    public Paint getPaintObject() {
        return myPaint;
    }

    protected abstract void setColor(int newColor);
}
```

**Eraser.java**

```
public class Eraser extends Tool {


    public Eraser() {
        toolName = "ERASER";


        myPaint = new Paint();
        mFgPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        mFgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeWidth(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
        mFgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setColor(int newColor) {
        // Empty, since I cannot change the paint color of the eraser
    }

}
```

**Brush.java**

```
public class Brush extends Tool {

   
    public Brush() {
        toolName = "BRUSH";
        myPaint = new Paint();
        setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        mFgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeWidth(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
        mFgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setColor(int newColor) {
        myPaint.setColor(newColor);
    }
```

**Pencil.java**

```
public class Pencil extends Tool {

   
    public Brush() {
        toolName = "PENCIL";
        myPaint = new Paint();
        setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        mFgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeWidth(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
        mFgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mFgPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setColor(int newColor) {
        myPaint.setColor(newColor);
    }
```

Comment: Do tools other than Eraser always all need to use the same color? Or are there situations were other tools sometimes also need a different color? A possible solution would be for tools to have a color config, were the eraser is tied to the background color config, and the other tools to the foreground color config.

Comment: Yep all tools besides Eraser should have the same color consistently. Interesting suggestion, but wouldn't that require updating each tool individually when the onColorChange() method is called? I know it's not a big deal with 2-3 tools, but if I had 10 more, I'm trying to think of making it easy to scale.

Comment: That depends on your exact implementation. If your tools would share a single configuration object, you only need to update that configuration and your tools will automatically use that (whether that is the right approach depends on factors I can't judge without more context). You could also register your tools as listeners with a configuration object, and make the configuration object responsible for notifying the registered tools, etc.

Comment: That sounds interesting - super new to this, so do you have any examples or something to link to where I can see something similar? Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to add a new abstract class `ColorableTool` extending `Tool` which stores the method `setColor`
`Eraser` will extend `Tool` while `Brush` and `Pencil` will extend `ColorableTool`
If your project goes more into polymorphism you should check interfaces for such behavior (in Java) ! :)

### Edit 1

You might check your current tool is a `ColorableTool` using `instanceof` like this

```java
if(currentTool instanceof ColorableTool) {
  // Do Stuff
}
```

### EDIT 2

As you want to update every color I suggest to use a `static` paint, an instance of paint shared among the `Tool` (or `ColorableTool` if you implemented my solution).
It should look like

```
public abstract class Tool {

    protected String toolName;
    static final Paint myPaint = new Paint(); // A shared paint between tools

    public String getToolName() {
        return toolName;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return myPaint.getColor();
    }

    public Paint getPaintObject() {
        return myPaint;
    }

    public static void setColor(int newColor) {
        Tool.myPaint.setColor(newColor);
    }
}
```

Therefore calling `Tool.setColor` will update color for every tool !

Comment: So ColorableTool would just be `Tool`, but with the `setColor` method while I remove it from `Tool`? If that's the case, how would I assign `currentTool`, since I call all Tool-related methods on that since it references the active one.

Comment: I've edited my answer, a `ColorableTool` is still a `Tool` as it should extend the abstract class `Tool`.

Comment: Also, in terms of the interfaces, I did a lot of research and it seemed like they're quite similar, except Abstract Classes allowed me to put all common / redundant methods in the abstract class, allowing only tool-specific logic to reside in each Tool class. Would using an interface instead solve my issue though? & to address your recent edit, alright thanks I'll give it a go!

Comment: @gosen32993 on your precise case there's no big difference, you might implement multiple interfaces but you might extend a single class.
If your tool should be `Colorable` and `Moveable` and some must be `Movable` but not `Colorable` and so on ... Interfaces are useful in this precise case !

Comment: @gosen32993 do you want me to write a sample of code to fit your project ?

Comment: Ohh, so I can make a Tool interface for all of the tools to implement, and also a Colorable interface with the `setColor` method for only the Brush/Pencil to implement?

Comment: Yeah, that would be super helpful actually, whether you want to use abstract class or an interface!

Comment: @gosen32993 I think I misread your post, you actually want to update EVERY color of EVERY tools in one method ?

Comment: Yeah, so basically, when the onColorChange() event is recieved, I want to change the color of every tool (with the option for tools like the Eraser to not have to change their color). I know I can just do `myBrush.setColor(newColor); myPencil.setColor(newColor)`, but if I have like 10-20 tools at some point, I'd like a more concise way to do that. So say I am drawing with the pencil and set the color to blue. The behavior should be that if I switch to the Brush next, it's already set to blue as well. The catch is, if I switch to Eraser, it should still be the background color.

Comment: @gosen32993 edit 2 is here !

Comment: Ah I see, `static` was the key! So from here, if I want to prevent the Eraser from being changed, I assume I can't override a static method in the `Eraser.java` class, so would the next best implementation be to split it into two classes / interfaces like you suggested?

Comment: Why does the eraser has a color ? Either switch to `ColorableTool` either `Eraser` has acces to it but do not use it :)

Comment: Ah well, Eraser has a color because it's similar to Brush, except it paints the background color onto the canvas (thus it must not be changed).

Comment: So `Eraser` always paint with a second color right ? 
You should either "draw" with another color shared between tools or declare it in Eraser only depending on your project.
If other tools has access to `backgroundColor` shared it through `static`
If not declare it in Eraser and eraser will use this color to do stuff